# How to concatenate two maps in apex

Tags: concatenation, apex

I have two maps, different sObject fields are being stored, one for each sObject. I want to add the fields from map1 to the beginning of map2 or vise-versa.

Is it possible to add the contents of one map to another without merging similar fields or keys? Can the values in a map that is an array be placed in such a way that they come after the values of the first map?

Comment: Are the 2 Maps of different sObject types? such as `Map<Id,Contact> and Map<Id,Account>`?? Maybe a bit of example code of what you're going for would make this question easier to understand

Comment: I agree with @KDH in that, I don't understand the question, you stated that your maps are `Map<String, String>` so what do you mean by _"without merging similar fields or keys"_?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the putAll(fromMap) method : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new Map<String, String>();
map1.put('Red','FF0000');
Map<String, String> map2 = new Map<String, String>();
map2.put('Blue','0000FF');
// Add map1 entries to map2
map2.putAll(map1);
System.Debug(map2);
//map2 = {Blue=0000FF, Red=FF0000}
```

If you want to go the other way : `map1.putAll(map2);`

Comment: My maps are actually different Map<String, String>

Comment: Use Map<String, sObject>